# magento 2.4.3: my product can not show image

Tags: magento2.4.3

my block onsale_pro added widgets with type "Catalog Products Pist" and I show this block on page Home Page. But my product can not show image
please! help me!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Look like static is missing from your url. please check your media path

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command ;

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

Comment: it's not work...

Comment: does that Product Page or category page show images for this product?

Comment: yes............

Answer (score 0):

I think this url is the problem: http://magento.demo2.com/media/catalog/product%5Ccache%5Ca3a5fab46ded5c197ff7844fd9e08957%5C//u/r/urn_aaid_sc_us_a1b326b9-062f-484a-b97d-39dbdbe93333.png
[image]
I try to magento ver 2.4.1, it's work with url:
[http://magento.demo1.com/pub/media/catalog/product\cache\b4e8de718b7e887c717a385beaed19df\//u/r/urn_aaid_sc_us_a1b326b9-062f-484a-b97d-39dbdbe93333_4_.png](http://magento.demo1.com/pub/media/catalog/product%5Ccache%5Cb4e8de718b7e887c717a385beaed19df%5C//u/r/urn_aaid_sc_us_a1b326b9-062f-484a-b97d-39dbdbe93333_4_.png)

I don't no why
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's show up after I'm restart my computer, unbelievable @@
[image]